# AS3 BlendMode ADD

Tags: actionscript-3

I could use some help about applying changes to symbols. I can see in the hints stuff like display/BlendMode/Properties/ADD for example, same things can be changed directly, in symbol properties. I don't really know the rules, which one to type where. I tried "Object01.display.BlendMode.Properties.ADD = true" and "Object01.draw(BlendMode.ADD)"... I've only found examples where people used it during drawing things using AS3. And I need to apply it to an existing symbol(instance). Via function, of course. Please.

if(myWill = true){
"change_blending_properties_code"
}

^_^

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with the documentation.  Guessing isn't going to take you far: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign any DisplayObject's [**flash.display.DisplayObject.blendMode**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#blendMode) quite easily in code:

```
import flash.display.BlendMode;

myDisplayObject.blendMode = BlendMode.ADD;
```

[**flash.display.BlendMode**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BlendMode.html) is simply a class of constants, like `BlendMode.ADD`.  Alternatively, you could write the following, but I don't recommend it:

```
myDisplayObject.blendMode = "add";
```

Comment: Get it, thanks. About import - is it like some libraries are not loaded and need to be called for? I tried changing blending without import, it worked. In what cases import is necessary?

Comment: And about the documentation, it's not very helpful. It lists the effects and describes them. Say, I see a pile of things, I ask what is it, Adobe says "duh, it's bricks, concrete and tiles!" and I say "sure, but what combination gives me a house?" which you just answered, thanks =D